# ArcGIS mobile to use external GPS device

Tags: gps, ios, arcgis-mobile

Im currently tasked to create an app that would sketch a GPS Device's movement and plot it on the ArcGIS map. By default, the ArcGIS locationDisplay class calls the IOS class CLLocation to retrieve the GPS data in which it only uses the internal GPS of the iPhone.

My question is: Is there any way to force the iPhone to use the GPS of an external device? Or can we configure the ArcGIS to use the data from the external device?

Comment: the i device needs to be jailbroken. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2243991?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do this? Do you need better accuracy or resolution than the internal GPS can provide? There may be alternative solutions to external GPS units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First how are you planning to connect the external GPS to your iOS device?

Because you either have to purchase an external GPS that already has the capability to connect to an iOS device, or the GPS device can transmit the location via Bluetooth Low Energy (LE).

Apple doesn't allow any device to communicate with their iOS devices unless it's part of the [MFi](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) program.

After that placing the coordinates on to the map is a piece of cake, first you have to keep in mind that any GPS device will give you coordinates in Lat/Lon (Spatial Refrence with WKID 4326), so you'll have to project that to your map's coordinate system.

After that you'll just create an AGSGraphic and place it on the map with the geometry and symbology that you can define.

Here is some code to do that :

```
AGSPictureMarkerSymbol *gpsSymbol = [[AGSPictureMarkerSymbol alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"ArcGIS.bundle/GpsDisplay.png"];

AGSGraphic *gpsGraphic = [[AGSGraphic alloc] initWithGeometry:<Your Geometry> symbol:gpsSymbol attributes:nil infoTemplateDelegate:nil];
```

Then just add the gpsGraphic to the map.

Comment: Hi Khattab. I have a Hemisphere GPS device to use and a Roving Network RN340 wifi serial adapter that transmits the data of the GPS device. My main concern is how to retrieve that data using my app.

Comment: You'll probably then need to create an HTTP Server on your iOS app, that the RN340 will post the data to, here's a tutorial to get you started on this: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html

Comment: Hi Khattab. I think that is a good idea. there is an IOS app provided by Roving Networks that connects to the RN340 and receives its data. I believe essentially, my app should do the same.

Comment: Cool, tell me if you need any help

Comment: Finally linked my app to the wifly module and now retrieving GPS data. But encountered another roadblock. How to i force ArcGIS IOS to use that data as the location display? currently im just retrieving one point since my GPS receiver is not moving.

Comment: I added some code to help you do the above.